# Why can't I authenitcate a registered user for this simple MEAN app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, mongoose, jwt

First of all, let me give you a **warm** thank you for giving a thought to this question.

So, what's the problem?

(This is a simple problem for most of you grandmasters!)

Well, the user can be registered to this simple app. But, for some reason, **authentication doesn't work**. That *some reason* is what my brain nerves having a hard time comprehending! 
Having tried all the possible solutions for hours and hours, this novice-newbie decided to head over to the haven of veterans here in the StackOverflow!

Let me give you the code, so you can shed me some bright light!

Following is a capture of the code written for the authentication

```js
//Authenticating the user

router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {

    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;



    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {

            return res.json({
                sucess: false,
                msg: 'There is no such user found here'
            });
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {

            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                });
                res.json({

                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT' + token,
                    user: {

                        id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        username: user.username,
                        email: user.email
                    }

                });
            } else {

                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'Enter the correct details!'
                });

            }

        });



    });



});


//Getting into the dashboard

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {

        res.json({
            user: req.user
        });

    });
```

The next few pictures on your way shows you the POSTMAN requests that are done by this novice.

Here, a post request is done to register the user and as you can see, there's not a smidgen of a problem there; the user is, without a doubt, registered!

[image: **postman pic**]

Here's the authentication done with POSTMAN

[image: postman pic2]

But now, for some reason (which I have zero clue of), the user is NOT authenticated. This is the problem that I need to solve.

Here is a code of the model/user.js file in case you want to know what's in there as well

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

// These are the collection or entities in ERD language
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema); //User is the name give for this particular model's schema

// these are functions implemented to do a certain task
module.exports.getUserById = function (id, callback) {

    User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (username, callback) {
    const query = {
        username: username
    }

    User.findOne(query, callback);

}

module.exports.addUser = function (newUser, callback) {

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);

        });
    })

}


//comparing the hash password

module.exports.comparePassword = function (candidatePasword, hash, callback) {

    bcrypt.compare(candidatePasword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        callback(null, isMatch);
    });
}
```

Thank You for your time!

Stay safe btw!

edit1: The code for the registration or signing up.

```js
router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {

    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password

    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {

        //console.log("registration is working");

        if (err) {
            res.json({
                sucess: false,
                msg: 'Hey! Enter the correct information man!'

            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                msg: 'you are registered'

            });
        }
    });

});
```

Here's the whole routes/users.js file for you to refer

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');





// Signingup the user

router.post('/signup', (req, res, next) => {

    let newUser = new User({
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password

    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {

        //console.log("registration is working");

        if (err) {
            res.json({
                sucess: false,
                msg: 'Hey! Enter the correct information man!'

            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                msg: 'you are registered'

            });
        }
    });

});


//Authenticating the user

router.post('/authenticate', (req, res, next) => {

    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;



    User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (!user) {

            return res.json({
                sucess: false,
                msg: 'There is no such user found here'
            });
        }

        User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {

            if (err) throw err;
            if (isMatch) {
                const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 604800 // 1 week
                });
                res.json({

                    success: true,
                    token: 'JWT' + token,
                    user: {

                        id: user._id,
                        name: user.name,
                        username: user.username,
                        email: user.email
                    }

                });
            } else {

                return res.json({
                    success: false,
                    msg: 'Enter the correct details!'
                });

            }

        });



    });



});


//Getting into the dashboard

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {
        session: false
    }),
    (req, res, next) => {

        res.json({
            user: req.user
        });

    });



router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {

    let newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        password: req.body.password
    });

    User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {

        if (err) {
            res.json({
                success: false,
                msg: "Enter the correct information"
            });
        } else {
            res.json({
                success: true,
                msg: "User loggedIn"
            });
        }

    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What do you guys think the error is? I just can't seem to find any error whatsoever!

Comment: Where is the code for user register?

Comment: Wait for a second, I'll upload it now

Comment: Yeah you are right! That's why I did add the text of it

Comment: Anyway, now the problem is solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your schema, you don't have the field `username` but your query is `{username: username}`. That's why you can't find any user match and get the response "There is no such user found here". Change your query to `{name: username}` may solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cuong. I'll do the update and see if it works! Thanks again!

Comment: Thank Cuong for your time. It worked! I'm a rookie! Thanks again!